# Students' records

Tags: c++, struct, binary, binaryfiles

I am trying to save a data of students' records into a text file and a binary file, but the output doesn't allow me to enter any data, and i can't find where is the problem. Anyone can help ?

I opened a text file and a binary file, and I used function.
the visual studio 13 does not show me any error.

```
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>

    struct dof { int DD, MM, YYYY; };

    struct record
    {
        string firstname;
        string lastname;
        string adress;
        string highschooldegree;
        int phonenumber;
        int ID;
        int group;
        int coursescore[5];
        char grade;
        float GPA;
        dof birthday;
    }student;

void getdata(ifstream &, record &student);
void getdatabin(ifstream &, record &student);
void outputdata(ofstream &, record &student);
void outputdatabin(ofstream &, record &student);

int main()
{
    record student;
    ifstream infile;
    ifstream infilebin;
    ofstream outfile;
    ofstream outfilebin;

    infile.open("student.txt", ios::in | ios::app);
    if (infile.good())
        getdata(infile, student);
    else
        cout << "File cant be opened " << endl;
    infile.close();

    outfile.open("student.txt", ios::out);
    if (outfile.good())
        outputdata(outfile, student);
    else
        cout << "File cant be opened " << endl;
    outfile.close();

    infilebin.open("student.bin", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::app);
    if (infilebin.good())
        getdatabin(infilebin, student);
    else
        cout << "File cant be opened " << endl;
    infilebin.close();

    outfilebin.open("student.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
    if (outfilebin.good())
        outputdatabin(outfilebin, student);
    else
        cout << "File cant be opened " << endl;
    outfilebin.close();

    return 0;
}

void getdata(ifstream &infile, record &student)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        infile >> student.firstname;
        infile >> student.lastname;
        infile >> student.adress;
        infile >> student.highschooldegree;
        infile >> student.phonenumber;
        infile >> student.ID;
        infile >> student.group;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            infile >> student.coursescore[j];
        }
        infile >> student.grade;
        infile >> student.GPA;
        infile >> student.birthday.DD >> student.birthday.MM >> student.birthday.YYYY;
    }
}

void getdatabin(ifstream &infilebin, record &student)
{
    infilebin.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&student), sizeof(student));
}

void outputdata(ofstream &outfile, record &student)
{
    outfile << student.firstname;
    outfile << student.lastname;
    outfile << student.adress;
    outfile << student.highschooldegree;
    outfile << student.phonenumber;
    outfile << student.ID;
    outfile << student.group;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        outfile << student.coursescore[j];
    }
    outfile << student.grade;
    outfile << student.GPA;
    outfile << student.birthday.DD << student.birthday.MM << student.birthday.YYYY;
}

void outputdatabin(ofstream &outfilebin, record &student)
{
    outfilebin.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&student), sizeof(student));
}
```

Comment: Hello Miu, welcom to stackoverflow. Could you please supply us with some more specifics (e.g. which functions do get called). For a good idea of how to ask a question that will attract good answers, you might want to have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: are you sure that "student.txt" and "student.bin" are in the same directory of your programe?, somtimes this is a common mistake

Comment: @Youssef yes I am sure. I really cant find the problem in this code :/

Comment: @MIU_h_dragon , I see that you are using student.txt for input and ouput streams. so did you try using `infile.clear()` before `outfile.open("student.txt", ios::out);`

Comment: @Youssef still not working. It also shows me that the p1.exe ( the project name ) has stopped working

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can write the structure to file using :

```
outfilebin.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&student), sizeof(student));
```

it will write some pointers instead of string values;

Also, when you do

```
outfile << student.firstname;
outfile << student.lastname;
```

it will output all those strings together with no delimiter, something like "firstnamelastname15 ..."  how do you expect to read them back?

To write values to binary file, use a fix-sized structure like

```
struct student {
  char firstname[40];
  char lastname[40];
  int age;
}
```

You can read/write the whole structure to binary files.

To write values to text file, use a delimiter or fixed width:

```
fout << student.firstname << "\t" << student.lastname << "\t" << student.age << "\t" << std::endl;
```

To read them, read by lines and parse them into structure (you can use std string in your structure here).